# can I open a website/webapp within iphone app as part of one of the tabs

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone application with Tabbar. One of the tabs is UIWebView which opens a link to  a website in which you can login and do some tasks.

So the question is, 
Is it legal to have an iPhone application which allows you to login into website as part of application? I am not quitting the iphone  application while visiting the website.

Thanks
DPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you don't do any money transactions (i.e. eBay) in the website **it is legal**. If your intention is to use eBay or something like that inside the webview just open it externally in safari.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  However, if the website allows unfiltered access to the web - ie has a google search, or external links, or a URL bar, note that your app will have to be rated 17+ due to the ability to find adult content on the web.  As long as the website only has internal links, you should be fine.

However, Apple does sometimes have a cow about web interfaces not following Apple's UI Design guidelines, so make sure the buttons in your web page are big enough to be finger-touchable.

Comment: Is the 17+ thing still in place? I haven't seen one of those warnings in ages. Google+ has external links, Facebook too, and Tweetbot has an internal browser with URL bar. None are 17+.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not sure.  All I know is that with the App Store reviewers, safer is better (especially if you're not Google or Facebook)

Comment: Not if you're ditching functionality out of fear of something that's no longer true.

Comment: Well yes, but it seems that the aim of his application isn't to include general web browsing functionality, it's to log in and "do some tasks".  Speaking of which - make sure you provide a test login / password so that the reviewers can log in.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the explanation. The website I will be referring will only have internal links so I guess 17+ is not an issue :)